# Is ISL too basic after having completed a one-semester measure-theoretic statistics course?

Tags: machine-learning, references

I already know a good deal of measure-theoretic statistics from 1 semester-long course.

I want to learn machine learning.

The "Bible" in this field seems to be Elements of Statistical Learning. I have skimmed a few chapters, and it feels a bit of a tough read for my current level, but I do believe that I could manage to read it, if I put in the effort, and used google to fill in any gaps that may arise.

However, I also know there's Introduction to Statistical Learning, which focuses more on applications and R code. This may be a more manageable book to read, but I fear that it's too basic and aimed at people who don't know statistics all that much.

So my question is, is ISL too basic of a book for somebody who already knows statistics, and would my time be better spent doing the hard work it'll take to get through ESL? Or should I just quickly get through ISL, and then maybe take on ESL afterwards?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too much opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to this kind of question are likely to be primarily opinion-based.

My suggestion would be keep reading this book and skip the part you familiar with. For example, for linear method, you may know a lot and this book is too easy. On the other hand, tree based model, support vector machine, and unsupervised method (PCA) you may not know too much. This book is still good for you to learn those topics.

In addition, the [PRML book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732) may be another good resource for you.